# How to add dependsOn in VM extension script for HDI cluster with in same template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-deployment

I want do the following

1. Create HDI cluster (resource group 1) and 2 VMs (resource group 2) are in parallel
2. Run Extension script in VM1 after HDI and VM1 are deployed
3. Run Extension script in VM2 after VM1 and VM2 are deployed

I am getting error as below

> ERROR: Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource
>   'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/clusterTemplate' is not defined in
>   the template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template for usage
>   details.'.

How can I solve this issue?

```
{
        "apiVersion": "[variables('resourceDeploymentApiVersion')]",
        "name":"[variables('clusterTemplateName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "resourceGroup": "[parameters('clusterResourceGroupName')]",
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "[variables('clusterTemplateURL')]"
            },
            "parameters": {
                "clusterName": { "value": "[parameters('clusterName')]" 
            }
        }

    },          
    {
        "apiVersion": "[variables('resourceDeploymentApiVersion')]",
        "name": "[variables('vmTemplateName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "resourceGroup": "[parameters('vmResourceGroupName')]",
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "[variables('vmTemplateURL')]"
            },
            "parameters": {
                "appid": { "value": "[parameters('appid')]" }
            }
        }             
    },

    {
        "apiVersion": "[variables('resourceDeploymentApiVersion')]",
        "name": "[variables('vmTemplateName1')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "resourceGroup": "[parameters('vmResourceGroupName')]",
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "[variables('vmTemplateURL1')]"
            },
            "parameters": {
                "appid": { "value": "[parameters('appid')]" }
            }
        }             
    },
 {
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
        "name": "[concat('vmName','/install-script')]",
        "apiVersion": "[variables('computeApiVersion')]",
        "location": "[variables('location')]",  
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', variables('clusterTemplateName'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', variables('vmTemplateName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
            "type": "CustomScript",
            "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
            "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
            "settings": {
               "fileUris": ["[variables('installScript')]"]
            },
            "protectedSettings":{
                "commandToExecute": "[concat('bash init.sh', ' ', parameters('appId'))]"
            }
        }
    },{
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
        "name": "[concat('vmName','/install-script')]",
        "apiVersion": "[variables('computeApiVersion')]",
        "location": "[variables('location')]",  
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', variables('vmTemplateName'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', variables('vmTemplateName1'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
            "type": "CustomScript",
            "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
            "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
            "settings": {
               "fileUris": ["[variables('installScript')]"]
            },
            "protectedSettings":{
                "commandToExecute": "[concat('bash init.sh', ' ', parameters('appId'))]"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the issue by using cluster resource group name in resourceId

Before:-

```
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', variables('clusterTemplateName'))]",
```

After:-

```
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId(parameters('clusterResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments', variables('clusterTemplateName'))]",
```